# Elimination ordering

Tags: code-golf, array

Your task is to remove smallest amount elements from a list, so the most elements are on their corresponding place. The element is on it's corresponding place, when it's value is equal to it's position.

Let's look at this example list:

```
1 5 3 2 5
```

This list has three elements on their corresponding place (1 on position 1, 5 on position 5, 3 on position 3).

### Input

The input is a sequence of decimals in any reasonable format. For example:

```
1 3 2 3 6
```

### Output

The output is a sequence of decimals in any reasonable format which contains, as its first element, the amount of elements removed from the input then the corresponding, 1-based element positions removed.

For example, for input given above, the (correct) output:

```
1 2
```

instructs us to remove one element, the one at index two (the first `3`), which will leave us with `1 2 3 6` which has three elements at their index positions.

This output would be incorrect:

```
2 2 5
```

Since although removing the two elements at indexes two and five would leave us with `1 2 3` which *also* has three elements at their index positions, we've removed more than the minimal necessary.

### More complicated example

```
1 2 3 3 4 5 6
```

In this case you can remove **either** of 3's, but not both (so `1 3` and `1 4` are both acceptable outputs).

```
1 3 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

In this case, if you would remove 3 on position 2, it would pass more elements, than if you would remove 3 on position 4 (so `1 4` is incorrect while `1 2` is correct).

```
1 3 2 3 5 6 7 8 9
```

Here removing 3 on position 2 is a mistake, because this actually makes the situation worse in obvious way (there are now less correctly placed elements than before). (the correct output is `0` since removing no elements is the best thing to do)

```
1 7 2 8 1 3 9
```

In this case we want to remove the three elements at positions 2, 4, and 5 (leaving us `1 2 3 9` for three in the correct location) so the correct output would be `3 2 4 5`)

### Rules

- This is code golf, so the shortest code wins!
- Loopholes are forbidden.
- Assume that input is valid, contains nothing more than digits and spaces, and the input numbers inside the string are decimals in range of 0 <= n <= 99.
- Please include a link to an online interpreter for your code.
- If anything is unclear, please let me down in the comments.

Comment: Can we use 0 based indices?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I want to make it uniform, so only 1 based indices are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
lBhMh.Ms.eqktb.DQZyU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8cpwzdDz7dYL7UwuyRJzyUwqjL0//9oQx0FIx0FYzAy0VEw1VEwiwUA)

Comment: It was stated clearly that you have to.

Comment: Ok, edited the answer. I still don't understand why.

Comment: Because there is such requirement in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
JŒPṚœPF=J$SʋÞ⁸ṪL;$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//SsWSUOG5msWTUEY9SiRTyovDnuKBuOG5qkw7JP/Dh8WS4bmY//9bMSwgNywgMiwgOCwgMSwgMywgOV0)**

#### How?

```
JŒPṚœPF=J$SʋÞ⁸ṪL;$ - Link: list of numbers, A
J                  - range of length (A) [1,2,3,...,len(A)]
 ŒP                - all partitions      [[1],[2],...,[1,2],[1,3],...,[2,3],...]
   Ṛ               - reversed (so longest to shortest)
            Þ      - sort (the p's in all partitions) by:
             ⁸     -   (using the chain's left argument, A, as the right argument)
           ʋ       -   last four links as a dyad, i.e. f(p, A):
    œP             -     partition A at the indices in p
      F            -     flatten (to give result of dropping the values at indices in p)
         $         -     last two links as a monad:
        J          -       range of length (of the flatten result)
       =           -       equals? (vectorises)
          S        -     sum
              Ṫ    - tail (i.e. the shortest p which yields the maximal sum)
                 $ - last two links as a monad:
               L   -   length (of that result)
                ;  -   concatenate
```

---

An alternative for `=J$` is `ĖE€`